# What's the difference between cloning and restoring from backup?

Tags: bobiverse

Just getting into the third book of the Bobiverse and I realized that cloning new Bobs seems the same process as restoring a Bob from backup.  But new Bobs take a new name and they describe how personality is different for each "new" Bob.

But when Bobs are destroyed and they talk a lot about how he had (or didn't have) a recent backup and it's implied that this way the old Bob isn't dead.  Wouldn't those newly restored copies have the same jitter as the intentional clones?

What's the difference between a clone and a restored Bob?

Answer (score 3):

While not knowing the story you're talking about, you're probably facing the AI equivalent of genetic diversity.

In order to have a diverse, functioning complex system it is necessary to face the arising problems/situations from as many angles as possible.
 Conversely, if you'd just create 100% identical copies of a single AI and populate your area with them, a single arising problem that the original can't solve has a high chance of devastating, if not eradicating, the whole population.

So, what is done is this: 
Parameters of the copies shaping the robots "character" are randomly altered, even though correct data is available.

In this context it is also noteworthy that digital data, if handled correctly, *does not degrade at all*. May it be transmitting or saving, thanks to redundancy and error-correcting-code (ECC), you can detect virtually any error and correct it.

So, as summary: 
A backup is a faithful replication using stored backup-data. 
A clone is a copy that has been deliberately created to fulfill the purpose of diversity.

---

Edit:
If the direct logic reasoning is wrong, and the author doesn't specify it, then unless somewhere the author does actually specify it, there's no way to achieve a satisfying answer since there are just too many possibilities.

To illustrate it: For all we know, there could be a stupid line in the cloning-code that says:
 "Act like you're another person with another name, or you'll instantly be deactivated"

Now our poor little Bobs, desperately trying to stay alive, will act as if they're other persons and might not even dare to think like they did before, since they want to stay alive.

Comment: I **do** know the novels involved here and you are correct. Clones are replications of a computer AI (although based on a real person)...backups are copies of clones available so that clones can be restored if destroyed.

Comment: https://www.fantasticfiction.com/t/dennis-taylor/we-are-legion-(we-are-bob).htm

Comment: I agree with your theory, if it were intentional, but the diversity in the books is described as being a byproduct of small variation in hardware that's neither intentional nor controllable.

Comment: @Paulie_D that doesn't answer my question so much as restate it. I know they use them differently, my question is what makes this possible? As described, the backup/restore always results in a slightly different Bob

Comment: Your question asks is there a difference between a cloning and a restoration and the answer is yes. The author doesn't explain why...he just indicates that there **is** a difference.

Comment: @Paulie_D I thought my question pretty clearly asked *what* is the difference, not *is* there a difference.

Comment: I'm aware and theI above answer basically covers the difference. I dont know of any instances where the restored backup was a different entity from the one destroyed. Do you have an example? Clones were new entities and took new names. Restored backups did not.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is we (and the Bobs) dont know, the causes of changes in personality between the bobs is never explained, left as somthing the bobs accept and think about but are never able to answer however if you consider one of the main rules that was placed down by the first Bob on creating his first clones.

Each version must have its own name and therefore its own identity. Each new Bob is free to ake his own decisions and choices and cannot be forced to carry out a certain activity by the Bob that made it.

A Copy/Backup is taken with the intention of uploading it immediatley after the original version has been destroyed. Therefore there will only ever be 1 version of Homer, or Bill, or Bob existing at any 1 time. But if that version is destroyed then the copy is booted up and continues from the same point as the last. This means whatever its aims and goal where, whatever these where so it would continue on this track carying out these tasks for the same purpose. Now, it may be that glitches in the copying process may indeed twea the personality of this copy but with nothing to compare it with who is to say what has been caused by the process of copying and what is just the natural development of that individual. Now at several points throghout the books the individuals are seen to change, Ricker stops with the startrek theme, other Bobs change there VR's over time. Who is to say this isnt partly down to the copying of a Bob after it was destroyed?

A Clone is a copy that is taken and then given a new identity, it has the memories of the "parent" but from the emoment of creation individuality is encouraged, a new and different name. In most cases the ability and freedom to choose there goals and where they want to travel, the visuals of the VR etc. This means that the differences between each other become pronounced because you can compare the changes and development against the parent model.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, **Full Disclosure:** I have only limited experience with the Bobiverse and *We Are Bob,* so am by no means an expert. What I offer here is pure educated guess and speculation. That being said, there are a few possible explanations. I'll use examples to back them up where able:

**1. The Different Twin Phenomena:**  While not clones, identical twins *Are* essentially exact genetic duplicates. By most logical assumptions, this should imply they would be identical in all other aspects, correct? By and large, though, this doesn't happen; even being raised in the same household by the same parents, most twins tend to develop unique quirks unto themselves, even if they are close and share many similarities. On a mental/emotional level, standard bio-chemistry aside, people will react to various situations differently, and thus personalities form differently; on a physical level, for all their genetic matching, even twins have natural variations on *some* things, like finger prints. It's not unreasonable to assume something similar happens with the Bobs.

**2. Influence of time on personality.**  I have yet to find a concrete theory that shows out personalities are "hardwired" into us at birth. There *have* been studies that show why certain traits (say, aggression, competitiveness, calmness, altruism, fearfulness, etc) may have a genetic component, or even be subject to a type of "genetic memory"... for example, its held commonly among West Indians that Jamaicans tend to be more prone to rebelliousness and confrontation than say, Barbadians/Bajans, Kititians or Grenadians. Jamaica itself was home to a large number of the Maroons---- Africans who escaped slavery and established free communities in the mountainous interior, living off the land and forming occasional raid parties or guerrilla groups.

But there *is* some basis for this on a genetic level: much like Australia was a penal space, Jamaica, at that time, was not only a plantation site, but also used as a holding point for the most strong minded, rebellious and some historical notes say even aggressive of African transplants. If aggression can be passed down via genetics (as discussed in one article here: https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/07/180709101117.htm) then *deliberately*  putting the *most* aggressive of a populace in one place for generations *could* create a breeding ground for that trait to be predominant, if not at the very least fostered via social interaction. Even if brought under a certain amount of social control via  societal rules and laws, the fact remains that the higher genetic *potential* for aggression is still there. But how that trait would manifest in a time when social aggression is *minimized,* now... that is a whole other aspect.

The general idea is that the period a person is born in has something to do with how their personality develops. This is *not*  related to the Zodiac, but more akin to Seasonal affectation disorders; broad studies have shown that those born at different times of the year, for whatever reason, showcase different traits.  This has been discussed for over 2 decades: https://time.com/4741094/season-birth-personality/

Considering that a "Restored" Bob wouldn't in most cases have been "initiated" at the same season, month, time of day, and in some cases *year* as their predecessor, it's not unreasonable to think this too may have had *some* impact into how this new version continues on, or develops differently.

My final answer will attempt to directly address the difference between "cloning" and "restoring from backup", as I *believe* you are trying to differentiate.

**3. Cloning vs Restoration.** I don;t know if you are familiar with the *Bio-Booster Armor Guyver* Franchise, but it's a long running sci-fi manga series. Essentially, a teenager, Sho Fukamachi, comes into contact with an alien unit that bonds to him and gives him super human abilities he has to use to fight a vile corporation with ties to an ancient alien conspiracy. This guyver unit even possesses the ability to *Completely regenerate the host's body from a control medal,* with everything from their memories and emotions to seemingly their "soul" in tact. And when I say "Completely regenerate," I mean **completely!** To date, Sho has been melted, cut into pieces, *completely disintegrated by an alien made, meteor-busting demi-god*  ...and he's come back fine.

The reason I bring this up is because when it first happened, Sho was uncertain if he was the same guy with a new body, or a clone with his memory and personality simply "downloaded" into this new form. Thing was, he still had a scar he had from before he activated the guyver unit, and a *Clone* body would be a **complete regeneration of all tissue,** not just a "Fully regenerated" body with all the past marks and alterations made via a lifetime of living.  In this way, I offer that a "Rebooted" Bob maybe less a "clone" or copy, and more a "fully regenerated body", the way Deadpool can regenerate, but is the same guy. The *difference* is that a "restored" Bob *only* has the memories/personality, and the body is more or less totally new.

Contrast this, to say, **Star Trek:TNG** where in the episode *Second Chances,* a past transporter accident created two William Rikers, the one we knew on the Enterprise (Commander), and a version of himself..... that was *just as much* himself..... that remained on the planet and developed differently some 5 years or so before (Lt. Riker). This is an interesting parallel, because *both* of these men were essentially **the same man** up unto the point where the transporter beam malfunctioned and brought one to the rescue ship and left one on the planet, at which point they began living two seperate lives. But their experiences, emotions..*everything* up to that point made them *completely* the same person.

I think the Bobs are similar in this vein, though not exact; *obviously* any "new" Bob is a copy, ala **Multiplicity,** but a "Restored" Bob has a little more wiggle room for argument. To differentiate themselves, Commander Riker remained "William" and his duplicate would be known from then on by their middle name, Thomas. Due to their meeting, it altered the courses of their lives somewhat, but Thomas went on to have a fulfilling life of his own... I believe *this*, in a nutshell, accounts for the difference in "new clones" versus "restored" clones.

So in short....

Any "new" clone can be seen as a copy, yes, but an entity which is essentially a blank slate/different guy who can make life choices for themselves.  Concurrently, a "Restored" Bob is the *same guy* he was previously, but having a new *physical* body that was cloned.

That's just opinion, but I think that's the easiest way to view the seperation.